# How show a group label in ng-table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Anyone knows how to create a group in a ng-table:

```html
<div>
    <div ng-controller="ContractsController" style="position: relative;background:whitesmoke; border:1px solid lightgray; border-radius:5px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:5px; height:330px;">
        <button prevent-default ng-click="tableParams.sorting({});tableParams.filter({});" class="btn btn-deufol btn-sm pull-right" style="width:150px;margin: 2px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Alle anzeigen</button>

        <div style="margin-top: 6px;">
            Gruppieren nach:
            <select ng-model="groupby" style=" font-weight:bold;"> 
                <option value="vPPickUp" label="Abgeholt">Abgeholt</option>
                <option value="vsHier1" label="Auftragsnummer">Auftragsnummer</option>
                <option value="lastModifiedDate" label="bearbeitet am">bearbeitet am</option>
                <option value="orderNo" label="Bestellnummer">Bestellnummer</option>
                <option value="locationName" label="Standort">Standort</option>                
                <option value="stateId" label="Status Kiste">Status Kiste</option>
                <option value="vPReadyForDispatch" label="Versandbereit">Versandbereit</option>
                <option value="vPADate" label="VPA Erstellung">VPA Erstellung</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id=container" class="scrollable-area table-responsive" style="position:relative;background:whitesmoke; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; height: 294px;">
            
            <%-- Sollte eigentlich eine Animation zeigen ... --%>
            <div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="loading" style="text-align:center;">Loading Data ...</div>
            
            <table class="table" ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" fixed-table-headers>
                <tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups">
                    <tr class="ng-table-group">
                        <td colspan="{{$columns.length}}">
                            <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows" style="color:#3D3D3D;">
                                <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': group.$hideRows, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !group.$hideRows }"></span>
                                <strong>{{ group.label }} {{ group.value }}</strong>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="data in group.data"
                            ng-click="loadSingleView(data.vsHier1, data.vsHier2, data.kolliNoIntern); setSelected(data.id)" ng-class="{{selected}}">
        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By this way angularjs only shows the group by value. Is there a way to show the group to?

Example:
If i group by a date, angular shows the group like "01.12.2014", "02.12.2014" ....

Example what i want:
"VPA Erstellung: 01.12.2014"

If anyone has a tip or solution, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information from the group.data object for all the items in that group by looking at the specific info on any elements of the group array (assuming the field that you're looking for is the same for all items of that group).

Since you won't have a group without at least 1 item, you can get the info you want from the first item in the group. In this example I am grouping by a field called "name" on my "Domain" object.  Ngtable simple showed the {{group.value}} so I modified it to show

Domain {{group.data[0].description}}: {{group.value}}

Answer (score 0):

Is this you wanted?

[group example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CBcbkc?p=preview)

```
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10          // count per page
    }, {
        groupBy: 'role',
        total: data.length,
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')(data, $scope.tableParams.orderBy()) :
                    data;

            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: not quite. Look at my example, i need a output like {{ key }} {{ value }}. Else "Date: 01.12.2014"